# How do I change the file modification date in the Jupyter Notebook startup file list?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

By default, the file modification date ("Last modified" column of the file) in the Jupyter Notebook file list shown as relative, e. g. "seconds ago", "5 minutes ago", "17 days ago" and so on.

[image: relative date in Jupyter Notebook tree]

But I would to see this date like ISO 8601 date (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`). This date can be seen at the "Last modified" relative date tooltip.

Since I have not found way to change date format with configuration options, I found appropriate [line of code](https://github.com/jupyter/nbclassic/blob/7752bd880122755c13273e0dad53fb66b8797f9b/nbclassic/static/tree/js/notebooklist.js#L944) that responsible for file tree generation in the source JS file `notebooklist.js`:

```
item.find(".item_modified").text(utils.format_datetime(model.last_modified));
```

I changed this line of code in contents of the Python [package](https://pypi.org/project/notebook/) `notebook` in desired way:

```
item.find(".item_modified").text(moment(model.last_modified).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
```

and packed this file into package, then installed this modified package. But nothing changed!

Where I'm wrong?